# Convert List<List<String>> to csv

Tags: java, csv

```
List<String> a=new ArrayList<>();
a.add("Ross");
a.add("Rachel")'
List<String> b=new ArrayList<>();
b.add("Chandler");
b.add("Monica")'
List<String> c=new ArrayList<>();
c.add("Joey");
c.add("Phoebe");
List<List<String>> x=new ArrayList<>();
x.add(a);
x.add(b);
x.add(c);
```

I want to convert the list of list of strings x to csv? How to achieve that?

The csv should look like-

Ross Rachel

Chandler Monica

Joey Phoebe

Comment: The “C” in CSV stands for “comma”. Did you mean to put commas between names? And do you want to print the result to stdout or put it into a String variable with embedded new lines? Can you show what you’ve tried? This site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You did not show your attempt yet, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple csv writer could look like this:

```
Writer out = System.out; // this could be a FileWriter, StringWriter, etc.
for (List<String> line : x) {
    int n = 0;
    for (String field : line) {
        if (n++ > 0) {
            out.write(",");  // field separator
        }
        out.write(field);
    }
    out.write("\n"); // record separator
}
```

Not that if any of your strings contain a comma, that field should be wrapped with double-quotes, e.g. `"A,C"`.  The code above does not do that.  Fields that contain newlines or double-quotes should also be escaped. There's no single specification that defines how these escapes work in all cases, so that sometimes turns into trial and error to see what works in the app your file will be imported into.

Sometimes csv files have comma separated field names in the first first line, sometimes not.

Variants of csv use different characters for field separator, e.g. "\t" or "|"

There are libraries such as opencsv that handle these complexities, so for non-trivial cases it can be useful to use those instead of re-inventing basic functionality like this.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.